# Mongo database fileSize huge compared to storageSize

Tags: mongodb

I am running mongo 2.4.10, 3 node cluster (1 primary, 2 replica). Each instance is 8 cpu core, 30gb memory, 3.5 Tb disk space.

I am observing that one our databases has fileSize ~ 431Gb but the storageSize is just 54.65Gb. In other environments this isn't the case, fileSize is around ~ 65Gb.
(all sizes below in Gb)

```
db.stats(1024*1024*1024)
{
    "db" : "normalizeddb",
    "collections" : 13,
    "objects" : 7287222,
    "avgObjSize" : 7234.542869148216,
    "dataSize" : 49,
    "storageSize" : 54,
    "numExtents" : 160,
    "indexes" : 39,
    "indexSize" : 2,
    "fileSize" : 431,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 5
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I am wondering why would mongo preallocate SO much? I got some good info from http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/01/how-big-is-your-mongodb/ but this just indicates that fileSize would always be greater than storageSize.

Any idea anyone?

Comment: Have you removed a lot of the documents lately?

Comment: Not really, I have a ttl_ on one of the collections but it has been since months and not sure if that'd cause an issue. Does this fileSize indicate that at some point I had 430Gb of data (and now it may have shrunk)? I am sure that I never had more than 80-90Gb data ever, not sure why mongo preallocated so much?

Comment: MongoDB preallocates exactly 1 data file. This is done when the last file preallocated is used to store data for the first time. The TTL index has nothing to do with that directly. It is safe to assume that the  held ~429GB at one point in it's lifetime. However, there are ways to deal with it. Let the primary step down, shut it down and delete the data dir. Then, start `mongod` again - it will resync *the actual data* only. Rinse and repeat for the other instances (one by one) after the sync is done.

Comment: So help me understand, if at some point I had 400Gb+ data and then some delete occurred, it's going to create holes (as per link I submitted in question). Shouldn't even the storageSize be of the same order or maybe a little less (~200Gb)?

Comment: Also, do you guys think 'compact' or 'repairDatabase' commands help to shrink the fileSize?